# If $\forall \mathcal F(\bigcup \mathcal F = A \Rightarrow A \in \mathcal F)$ then A has exactly one element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

While working through Velleman's *How To Prove It*, I came across the following problem. Is my proof correct?

Suppose $A$ is a set, and for every family of sets $\mathcal F$, if $\bigcup \mathcal F = A$ 
then $A \in \mathcal F$. Prove that $A$ has exactly one element.

Proof. Existence: Suppose $A = \emptyset$. Then in particular, taking $\mathcal F = \emptyset$, 
we can conclude that if $\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset$ then $A \in \emptyset$. Since $\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset$,
it follows that $A \in \emptyset$, which is clearly a contradiction. Thus $A \neq \emptyset$. 
Uniqueness: Now suppose there are $x \in A$ and $y \in A$ such that $x \neq y$. Let $\mathcal G = \{ \{x\}, \{y\}, A \setminus \{x,y\} \}$.
Then in particular, taking $\mathcal F = \mathcal G$, we can conclude that if $\bigcup \mathcal G = A$ then
$A \in \mathcal G$. Clearly $\bigcup \mathcal G = A$, so $A \in \mathcal G$. But this is a contradiction since $A \neq \{x\}$,
$A \neq \{y\}$, and $A \neq A \setminus \{x,y\}$. Thus for all $x \in A$ and $y \in A$, $x = y$.

Comment: pousai re Stavro :)

Comment: Hey! Kalispera :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is fine, though the second part would work almost as easily with $\mathcal G=\{\{x\},A\setminus\{x\}\}$ for some $x\in A$: From $\bigcup \mathcal G=A$ we have $A=\{x\}$ or $A=A\setminus\{x\}$. The latter is contradiction if $x\in A$, hence the former a was to be shown ... That is one can prove $A=\{x\}$ for some $x$ instead of $x,y\in A\to x=y$; it's a matter of taste.

Comment: How do we know how to find such a set G={{x},A∖{x}} to contradict the hypothesis that x is not equal to y?

Comment: We're trying prove uniqueness, that A has a single unique element. We'll call that element x. The book suggests to use the contradiction strategy. When we do, we negate our goal and use it as a given. So what is the negation of "A's unique element is x". You might say, "suppose A has more than one element" but that wouldn't be sufficient since A={x,x} is more than one but the same. To negate, we need to say "A has elements that are not x", or to rephrase "A has an element x plus any number of element that are not x". The way to write this is $A \setminus \{x\}$. Hope this helps.