# $\cup \mathcal{F} = A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is in reference to

[If $\forall \mathcal{F} (\bigcup \mathcal{F} = A \rightarrow A \in \mathcal{F})$ then A has exactly one element.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460296/if-forall-mathcal-f-bigcup-mathcal-f-a-rightarrow-a-in-mathcal-f-the/)

and

[If $\cup \mathcal{F}=A$ then $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Prove that $A$ has exactly one element.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359550/if-cup-mathcalf-a-then-a-in-mathcalf-prove-that-a-has-exactly-one/)

The uniqueness proof involves supposing $x \in A$ and letting $\mathcal{F} = \{\{x\}, A \setminus \{x\}\}$. It is my understanding that this means that $\mathcal{F}$ contains two sets. The first is a set that only contains x. The second set contains any number of member that are not x. I suppose $A \setminus \{x\}$ could also be the empty set, but I cannot assume this.

In both posts the next step in the proof is to recognize that $\cup \mathcal{F} = A$. How is that right? Shouldn't $\cup \mathcal{F} = \{x, anotherMemberOfA, yetAnotherMemberOfA, ... \}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal F=\{X, Y\}$, then $\bigcup\cal F$ is just $X\cup Y$. What is $\{x\}\cup A\setminus\{x\}$?

Comment: It's A. $face \to palm$. Got it.